# __attribute__ ((noreturn)) generates warnings in Xcode 5.1 but not Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcc, xcode5, llvm

`__attribute__ ((noreturn))` generates warnings "Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match" in Xcode 5.1 but not Xcode 5.0.2 if I declare it in .m file and not .h.

Which version of Xcode is correct?

Comment: Can you show your code? I cannot reproduce the warning in Xcode 5.1.

Comment: @MartinR The warning only shows in Xcode 5.0.2.

Comment: Then why your question states *" generates warnings ... in Xcode 5.1 but not Xcode 5.0.2"* ?

Comment: Probably a good idea to use the same attribute both on the method declaration and the method implementation. Xcode creates more and more warnings in every new version, and usually these warnings are useful.

Comment: @gnasher729 Actually in this case the warning is less in newer version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: neither *and* both!

There is no formal definition of Objective-C, the rules are what the compiler implements. So neither is right as there is no definition to follow, but both are right as they define correctness themselves ;-)

You can report it is an inconsistency to Apple if you like, suggest how you think it should behave.

Comment: @Boon: `__attribute__((noreturn))` is not a part of C or C++. It's a feature of the compiler.

Comment: @Chuck Right that makes sense.